# nonce encryption in https

Tags: tls, web-application, api, nonce

I am thinking about using nonce and secure request to API Server. Is this the right implementation for using nonce?

#### PURPOSE

- Protect API Server from Replay attack
- Protect API Server from MITM attack
- Protect Core API Server from Resource exhaustion attack

#### IMPLEMENTATION

== ALL REQUEST IN HTTPS ==

PREPARATION:

- [CLIENT] check if [session_id]  exists

  - If exist use it
  - If not exist request [session_id] uuidv4 from [SERVER]
- [SERVER] generate [session_id] and store it in database ( redis )

BEFORE ANY IMPORTANT REQUEST:

- [CLIENT] request [snonce] from [SERVER] when submitting form / before api request with [session_id] or [auth_token_id :: if exist]
- [SERVER] check throttle limit based on [session_id] or [auth_token_id :: if exist]

  - If allowed, continue
- [SERVER] generates [snonce] with uuidv4, [snonce_id] with uuidv1
- [SERVER] store [snonce] to database ( redis ) with [session_id] + [snonce_id] + [snonce] + [time_created]

  - There will be a cleanup service on [SERVER], deleting expired and unused [snonce]
- [SERVER] return [snonce] + [snonce_id]
- [CLIENT] generates [cnonce] from uuidv4
- [CLIENT] generate [ticket] from SHA256

{ content = [snonce] + [auth_token :: if exist ], salt = [cnonce]   }

- [CLIENT] send ( [session_id] , [cnonce], [snonce_id], [ticket], [username :: if exist],  [payload] )
- [SERVER] checks if [ [session_id] + [snonce_id] exist in database and get all result ]
- [SERVER] delete used [snonce] on database
- If [username] exists, check and get [auth_token] from database
- [SERVER] check [ticket] with SHA256

{ content = [snonce] + [auth_token :: if exist ], salt = [cnonce]   }

- Proceed with the request if valid.

QUESTION:

- Is the above logic and implementation valid and secure?
- Is it necessary to generate cnonce and SHA256 it since the request is already in HTTPS TLS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)

Comment: These points are already covered by TLS. I don't know what a "Blind Attack" is, so some info on that would be nice.

Comment: @MechMK1, [deleted blind attack]. so all the hash and cnonce can be safely skipped? Thank you

Comment: I would *highly* recommend you to read about what TLS does for you, what attacks it mitigates and what is still up for you to do.

Comment: @MechMK1 will do, thank you very much for the link :)